# out of memory error when calling readAsArrayBuffer method on FileReader of the cordova-plugin-file (iOS)

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugin-file

On iOS I'm trying to upload videos to my own website and to do so I use the FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer method with a chunkSize of 1048576.

I upload chunks when the onprogress event fires and all of this actually works perfect except for bigger files. When trying to upload a file of 1.33GB i'm getting a out of memory exception when calling the readAsArrayBuffer method.

I guess this is because it's trying to reserve memory for the complete file, however this is not necessary. Is there a way to read a binary chunk from a file without it reserving memory for the complete file? or are there other solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are talking about [DOM File API/readAsArrayBuffer()](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#readAsArrayBuffer). That doesn't have a `chunkSize` parameter, i.e. it always reads the whole file.

Comment: well no parameter but the FileReader object does actually have a property. It isn't documented very well but you can set the FileReader.READ_CHUNK_SIZE property to use a specific chunk size. This however doesn't really work well (in my opinion). It still reservers memory for the complete file and then reads chunks and fires the onprogress event where you have to extract the chunk that has just been read from the entire array. There is code that I think was meant to deal with this, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself today by changing the plugin code, this is the original code:

```
FileReader.prototype.readAsArrayBuffer = function (file) {
   if (initRead(this, file)) {
       return this._realReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
   }

   var totalSize = file.end - file.start;
   readSuccessCallback.bind(this)('readAsArrayBuffer', null, file.start, totalSize, function (r) {
       var resultArray = (this._progress === 0 ? new Uint8Array(totalSize) : new Uint8Array(this._result));
       resultArray.set(new Uint8Array(r), this._progress);
       this._result = resultArray.buffer;
   }.bind(this));
};
```

and since at start progress is always 0, it always reserves the entire filesize. I added a propery READ_CHUNKED (because I still have other existing code that also uses this method and expects it to work as it did, i have to check to see that everything else also keeps working) and changed the above to this:

```
FileReader.prototype.readAsArrayBuffer = function(file) {
    if (initRead(this, file)) {
        return this._realReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }

    var totalSize = file.end - file.start;

    readSuccessCallback.bind(this)('readAsArrayBuffer', null, file.start, totalSize, function(r) {
        var resultArray;

        if (!this.READ_CHUNKED) {
            resultArray = new Uint8Array(totalSize);
            resultArray.set(new Uint8Array(r), this._progress);
        } else {
            var newSize = FileReader.READ_CHUNK_SIZE;
            if ((totalSize - this._progress) < FileReader.READ_CHUNK_SIZE) {
                newSize = (totalSize - this._progress);
            }
            resultArray = new Uint8Array(newSize);
            resultArray.set(new Uint8Array(r), 0);
        }
        this._result = resultArray.buffer;
    }.bind(this));
};
```

When the READ_CHUNKED property is true, it only returns the chunks and doesn't reserve memory for the entire file and when it is false it works like it used to.

I've never used github (except for pulling code) so i'm not uploading this for now, I might look into it in the near future.